# How do I store the type of an object in a variable?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I have a class that needs to be passed the type of an element, so I can later check if another object has either the type or is a subclass of this type and add it to an internal collection.

I have an `initialize:` method that gets called from the `new:` ctor of my class:

```
initialize: aType
    elements := OrderedCollection new.
    type := aType class.
```

Now I have a method that gets passed a value and should check if the types are compatible:

```
add: anElement  
    type isNil ifTrue: [ elements add:anElement. ^self. ].

    (anElement isMemberOf: type)
       ifTrue: [elements add:anElement.]
       ifFalse: [ ^ 'Not supported!' ].
```

This works if I want to check for a concrete type:

```
|myClass|
myClass:= MyClass new: '123'.

cc add: '5.4'. "Works"
cc add: 123.  "Fails correctly."
```

Now, to check if it's a derived type I modified the `add:`method:

```
add: anElement  
    type isNil ifTrue: [ elements add:anElement. ^self. ].

    (anElement isKindOf: type)
      ifTrue: [elements add:anElement.]
      ifFalse: [ ^ 'Not supported!' ].
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
|myClass|
myClass:= MyClass new: 5 asNumber.

myClass add: 5.4. "Fails, although Float is a sub type of Number"
```

I suspect that my initial method of determining the type of an object (`aType class`) is wrong, but I can't find a better, or more explicit way of determining the type. Basically, I'm looking for something like `typeOf(MyObject)` in C#. This is part of an exercise, so please excuse the contrived example :)

Comment: In your  last example you define the `myClass` variable and then execute `cc add: 5.4`. `cc` is another variable. If you execute this in the playground `cc` will be initialized will nil. What error do you get?

Comment: The problem is that `5 asNumber == 5` is a `SmallInteger` not a `Number`. Therefore `5.4` is not of a subtype of it.

Comment: @AndreiChis: Thanks for the info, that was a copy/paste error on my part. They are supposed to be the same.

Comment: Maybe also think of using a predicate (via a block), like `MyClass restrictedTo: [:x | x isInteger and: [x > 0]]` which subsume the other possibilities  `MyClass restrictedTo: [:x | x isMemberOf: Character]` or `MyClass restrictedTo: [:x | x isKindOf: Number]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment to your question, the problem is that `5 asNumber` is `5` which is an instance of `SmallInteger`, not an instance of `Number`. Thus, when you `initialize:` your class with `5` what you get in the ivar `type` is `SmallInteger`. And then, when you `add: 5.4`, the check becomes `5.4 isKindOf: SmallInteger`, which naturally fails.

I think that the problem originates in the way you have chosen to initialize the instance. A simpler approach would be to explicitly set the target `type` with a class, not an instance. Something on the lines of

```
initialize: aClass
  elements := OrderedCollection new.
  type := aClass
```

Then, your example will be something like

```
|myClass|
myClass:= MyClass new initialize: Number.
myClass add: 5.4.
```

which would accept `5.4` as an element because it is a `Float`, which `isKindOf: Number`.

Now let me add another remark. The usual semantics of `new:` is different from the one you used. The argument of `new:` is usually an `Integer` and such and integer expresses the desired size of the new instance. For example, you say `Array new: 3` when you want an `Array` with `3` entries, etc. It is not expected for `new:` to receive other kind of parameter for the construction of the object. I'm not saying it's forbidden, just that is not the usual naming convention. In your case I would suggest a method for instance creation such as

```
MyClass class >> on: aClass
  ^self new initialize: aClass
```

and your code would look like

```
| sequence |
sequence := MyClass on: Number.
sequence add: 5.                        "ok, 5 isKindOf: Number"
sequence add: 4.5.                      "ok, 5.4 isKindOf: Number"
sequence add: 'hello world'             "fail, not a Number"
```

Comment: Maybe something like `MyCollection of: Number` instead of on:?